# What are Magnus Shards?

Tags: ingress

A recent Ingress mail reported the latest information on these things called "Magnus Shards". I have never heard of them before. I read through the NIA Shard Manifestation Document but was unable to find anything that explains what they are.

What are Magnus Shards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shards are entities what appears somewhere. Players should lead the shard to their targets.

Shards can travel on links, and there are blue and green target portals. They are jumps in every 5 hours, this interval is depends on the event, determined by NIA.

If there is no link from the portal, after 4 unsuccess jump shard is jumping randomly near somewhere by current location. (This depends on the event too.)

Now a global event going. There are a lot of shards, and every shard is a piece of a character in the story of ingress by NIA.

Both faction wants to controll many character as they can by lead shards to their target. In this global

It is a style of gameplay of ingress. Check an intel map and try to locate them while game is going.

More and exact information is here:

http://investigate.ingress.com/2017/02/10/nia-shard-manifestation-document/

Here you can follow the actual gameplay, and also a timeline from the begining of the event: http://thrakazog.com/magnus/#t=Maps

Comment: How do you find out what the target portals are, per faction?

Comment: @A.R.Diederich There are big blue or green circles around the portal. 

You can see the whole event history and actual scores here: http://thrakazog.com/magnus/#t=Maps

Comment: That makes sense.I'd seen the current shard location, but missed the difference between that and the circled target. I'd assumed specific shards need to go to specific portals (Blue/Green), but it looks like any target portal (Blue/Green) can be used.

Comment: Shards has their own targets...